# Outgoing Email Settings

Tags: 2013, smtp

I'm getting an

> The e-mail message cannot be sent.  Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings are configured correctly.'

Here's what I've done:

- I've installed SharePoint 2013 on a VM.
- I have configured the IIS SMTP service (on the same VM) to send mail
  though my domain host (LFC).
- I dropped a test file in the 'Pickup' folder and it does indeed send.
- On the 'Outgoing email settings' page in SharePoint, I tried both the
  local machine name and the hosted domain name.

Both resulted in this same error.

What should the Outbound SMTP server be?  I would have thought the local machine since that's where the SMTP service is running, besides there isn't any place to enter SMTP credentials in SharePoint.

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: Review you followed all the steps outlined http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outbound SMTP server should be the domain that the SMTP server is whenever you open the IIS 6.0 Manager -> SMTP Server -> Domains -> Domain Name. In the picture below, the SMTP server would be `zjsptest.zjsptest.com`

[image]

Comment: I wasn't using a fully qualified name but instead only the machine name.  I changed it and it's not reporting an error anymore, but I haven't gotten an email yet.